# Efficient database lookup based on input where not all digits are sigificant

Tags: algorithm, database-design, relational-database, lookup

I would like to do a database lookup based on a 10 digit numeric value where only the first ***n*** digits are significant. Assume that there is no way in advance to determine ***n*** by looking at the value.

For example, I receive the value 5432154321. The corresponding entry (if it exists) might have key 54 or 543215 or any value based on n being somewhere between 1 and 10 inclusive.

Is there any efficient approach to matching on such a string short of simply trying all 10 possibilities?

**Some background**

The value is from a barcode scan. The barcodes are EAN13 restricted circulation numbers so they have the following structure:

02[1234567890]C

where C is a check sum. The 10 digits in between the 02 and the check sum consist of an item identifier followed by an item measure. There might be a check digit after the item identifier.

Since I can't depend on the data to adhere to any single standard, I would like to be able to define on an ad-hoc basis, how particular barcodes are structured which means that the portion of the 10 digit number that I extract, can be any length between 1 and 10.

Comment: One possibility would be to construct a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from the database keys, and search that trie in memory. Then load the record from the database, if found.

Comment: On an indexed column, 10 lookups really won't take that long. If you're looking for a database design (not a generic algorithm or data structure answer that may not be applicable to databases), I suggest you remove [tag:algorithm], and perhaps add the applicable database tag (but as I said - 10 lookups really won't take that long, and I'm not sure there's a much better way).

Comment: @JimMischel, thanks but I think the volume of data required to load into memory would be prohibitive.

Comment: @Dukeling, thanks, it could be that it's fast enough to look up 10 times, just checking that I wasn't missing something obvious.

Comment: You could construct the trie on disk and mount it as a memory mapped file. The biggest drawback, of course, is that you would have to rebuild the trie whenever you added or removed a key. How many keys are we talking about here?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few ideas here:

1)
Maybe store these numbers in reversed form in your DB.
If you have N = 54321 you store it as N = 12345 in the DB.
Say N is the name of the column you stored it in.

When you read K = 5432154321, reverse this one too,
you get K1 = 1234512345, now check the DB column N
(whose value is let's say P), if K1 % 10^s == P, 
where s=floor(Math.log(P) + 1).
Note: floor(Math.log(P) + 1) is a formula for
the count of digits of the number P > 0.
The value floor(Math.log(P) + 1) you may also
store in the DB as precomputed one, so that
you don't need to compute it each time.

2) As this 1) is kind of sick (but maybe best of the 3 ideas here), 
maybe you just store them in a string column and check it with 
'like operator'. But this is trivial, you probably considered it
already.

3) Or ... you store the numbers reversed, but you also
store all their residues mod 10^k for k=1...10.
col1, col2,..., col10
Then you can compare numbers almost directly, 
the check will be something like

```
N % 10 == col1
or
N % 100 == col2
or
...
(N % 10^10) == col10.
```

Still not very elegant though (and not quite sure
if applicable to your case).

---

I decided to check my idea 1). 
So here is an example
(I did it in SQL Server).

```
insert into numbers
(number, cnt_dig)
values
(1234, 1 + floor(log10(1234)))


insert into numbers
(number, cnt_dig)
values
(51234, 1 + floor(log10(51234)))

insert into numbers
(number, cnt_dig)
values
(7812334, 1 + floor(log10(7812334)))



select * From numbers

/*

Now we have this in our table:

 id  number  cnt_dig
 4   1234    4
 5   51234   5
 6   7812334 7

*/

-- Note that the actual numbers stored here 
-- are the reversed ones: 4321, 43215, 4332187.
-- So far so good.

-- Now we read say K = 433218799 on the input 
-- We reverse it and we get K1 = 997812334
declare @K1 bigint 

set @K1 = 997812334

select * From numbers
where
@K1 % power(10, cnt_dig) = number 

-- So from the last 3 queries,
-- we get this row:
-- id   number  cnt_dig
-- 6    7812334 7
-- 
-- meaning we have a match 
-- i.e. the actual number 433218799 
-- was matched successfully with the
-- actual number (from the DB) 4332187.
```

So this idea 1) doesn't seem that bad after all.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've finally managed to fit that into my head. I think the question is whether a single full table scan (required by your solution) will be faster than 10 indexed scans (as suggested by @Dukeling), that's something I'll just have to try out.